# c++ unordered_map iterator on single object

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

I have a string and an unordered_map of (string, Object). I already have some code in which I am iterating over the map:

```
for(auto& item : map) {
    do_something;
}
```

I want to modify it to do the part inside the for loop when the string is non-empty and found inside the map else if string is empty do it for all items in the map.

```
if(!string.empty()){
    item = map.find(string);
    do_something;
}
else {
    for(auto& item : map) {
        do_something;
    }
}
```

Can I do this without rewriting the do_something or creating a separate function?

Comment: Put `do_something` in a function local lambda?

Comment: Can I create some sort of iterator out of the pair from map.find() so that the for loop remains as is?

Comment: Not sure I follow your line of thought

Comment: something like 
temp = map or map.find();
for (item : temp){

}

Comment: Actually you can. Give me a moment.

Comment: What is `do_something;`? Or do you mean `do_something(item);`

Comment: @Walter yeah i mean do_something(item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow the line of thought you presented in the comments. You can replace the range for loop by a regular for loop over a specific range (defined by iterators). To define it, you'd need something like this:

```
auto begin = map.begin(), end = map.end(); // The whole map

if(!string.empty())
  std::tie(begin, end) = map.equal_range(string);
  // constrain range to the single element

for(; begin != end; ++begin) { // loop over it 
  auto& item = *begin;
  // Do something
}
```

The star of the above is [`std::unordered_map::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/equal_range).

Comment: This seems fine apart from time complexity. I am not very aware of internals. Is equal_range time complexity same?

Comment: @sum250 - The same as find's for this container (where duplicates are not allowed).